# get values in an object in object as array with es6

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm pulling data from a service that loads into a dropdown and when a value is selected it's being assigned to a variable and an example is below

```
[{
    "id": 482,
    "firstName": "Micheal",
    "lastName": "Bamford",
    "email": "lalacifay@cliptik.net",
    "areaCodes": [
        {
            "id": 60,
            "name": "New York",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "createdDate": "2018-10-30 14:09:28"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Florida",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "createdDate": "2018-10-30 14:09:28"
        }
    ],

    "createdDate": "2019-01-03 12:29:33"
}]
```

What i'm trying to achieve is to only get the `name` property in the `areaCodes` objects like this `['New York', 'Florida']`

Below is the code i'm using so far which only gets me only the first in the array

```
const selected = this.listFromAPI.filter(t => t.id === ev.id).map(r=> r.areaCodes[0].name);
```

Comment: What is ev.id?..

Comment: ev.id is the value grab from the dropdown after selection

Comment: listFromAPI is an array. Does it have other elements? Do you want names from all areaCodes from all elements, because you have filter with id in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And even shorter:

```js
const obj = [{
    "id": 482,
    "firstName": "Micheal",
    "lastName": "Bamford",
    "email": "lalacifay@cliptik.net",
    "areaCodes": [
        {
            "id": 60,
            "name": "New York",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "createdDate": "2018-10-30 14:09:28"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Florida",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "createdDate": "2018-10-30 14:09:28"
        }
    ],

    "createdDate": "2019-01-03 12:29:33"
}]


const res = obj[0].areaCodes.map(i=>i.name);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
const dataset = [{
  "id": 482,
  "firstName": "Micheal",
  "lastName": "Bamford",
  "email": "lalacifay@cliptik.net",
  "areaCodes": [{
      "id": 60,
      "name": "New York",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "createdDate": "2018-10-30 14:09:28"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Florida",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "createdDate": "2018-10-30 14:09:28"
    }
  ],

  "createdDate": "2019-01-03 12:29:33"
}];

for (const item of dataset) {
  const {
    areaCodes
  } = item;
  if (Array.isArray(areaCodes)) {
    const names = areaCodes.map(c => c.name);
    console.log(names);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#flatMap` and `array#map` to extract `name` from `areaCodes`.

```js
const data = [{ "id": 482, "firstName": "Micheal", "lastName": "Bamford", "email": "lalacifay@cliptik.net", "areaCodes": [{ "id": 60, "name": "New York", "status": "ACTIVE", "createdDate": "2018-10-30 14:09:28" }, { "id": 12, "name": "Florida", "status": "ACTIVE", "createdDate": "2018-10-30 14:09:28" } ], "createdDate": "2019-01-03 12:29:33" }],
    result = data.flatMap(o => o.areaCodes.map(({name}) => name));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think it also makes sense to use Set in order to get unique values

Comment: Yeah, it would be, but unfortunately, OP hasn't asked of unique value.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `filter`, `reduce` and `map`,

```js
const listFromAPI = [
  {
    id: 482,
    firstName: "Micheal",
    lastName: "Bamford",
    email: "lalacifay@cliptik.net",
    areaCodes: [
      {
        id: 60,
        name: "New York",
        status: "ACTIVE",
        createdDate: "2018-10-30 14:09:28",
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        name: "Florida",
        status: "ACTIVE",
        createdDate: "2018-10-30 14:09:28",
      },
    ],

    createdDate: "2019-01-03 12:29:33",
  },
];

// Value grabbed from drop down selector
const ev = {
  id: 482,
};

const result = listFromAPI
  .filter((t) => t.id === ev.id)
  .reduce((temp, currentVal) => {
    if (currentVal.areaCodes && Array.isArray(currentVal.areaCodes)) {
      currentVal.areaCodes.map((el) => {
        temp.push(el.name);
      });
    }

    return temp;
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
const selected = this.listFromAPI.filter(t => t.id === ev.id).map(r => r.areaCodes.map(areaCode => areaCode.name));
```